# Защитить svg картинки

Tags: html, svg

На сайте есть множество svg картинок,подскажите как лучше их защитить от копирования и есть ли смысл это делать?Сейчас можно просто посмотреть код и забарть все фотографии.

Comment: Как насчёт просто добавить ватермарку?

Comment: можно разделить стили и разметку усложнив тем самым жизнь тем, кто захочет это сохранить себе.

Comment: @ITCat в svg она стирается за пять секунд

Comment: как например можно усложнить разметку и стили? если ты можешь посмотреть все фотографии где лежит игра

Comment: так же можно сделать так, чтобы изображения формировались скриптом и их бы не было в ответе сервера в явном виде

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Независимо от формата изображения, не существует способа, позволяющего сделать невозможным его скачивание с сайта.